# Is it fine to say isomorphic or should one say isomorphic to each other?

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing

Is it fine to say "Groups $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic." or should one say "Groups $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic to each other."?

Comment: Both statements mean the same thing.

Comment: Both work, but it might not hurt to lean toward the latter as a beginner, or while writing for beginners-it's common for students to acquire from the formulation "Groups $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic" the idea that "The group $B$ is isomorphic" has a meaning on its own!

Comment: Question: "are the groups $A$ and $B$ isomorphic?" Answer: "group $A$ is isomorphic, but group $B$ is not". :)

Comment: Grammatically, "Groups $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic" appears to have the same syntax as "Groups $A$ and $B$ are abelian." But semantically they are quite different. Since "isomorphic" as a predicate requires *two* groups, I don't think there is any ambiguity here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both formulations are common.  You could also say "$A$ is isomorphic to $B$."

Comment: Okay, but I don't like to start a sentence with mathematical symbol.

Comment: @student "Group $A$ is isomorphic to $B$", then.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same thing. An isomorphism between $A$ and $B$ implies that your found a bijection between $A$ and $B$ that is also a homomorphism, which remains clear in both statements.